# Use the backbone.js client to save custom post type meta

Tags: rest-api, save-post, wp-api, backbone

So I have this small piece of code that renders an array of IDs:

```
const selected = this.$data.list.selected;
function get_ids(input, field) {
    const output = [];
    for (let i=0; i < input.length ; ++i)
        output.push(input[i][field]);
    return output;
}
const result = get_ids(selected, "id");
```

Now inside my JS, I want to be able to use the backbone.js API that WordPress provides to save it to my employee custom post type as a post meta.

So let's say that my result output is `[343, 3532]` - I want to be able to save that array as a "apps" post meta under employees.

I know examples showed that it would be something like `const test = new wp.api.models.Employee().fetch and then save`, but it sounds super confusing since I don't have a specific post, and would just like to save the post meta.

Based on these examples, does anyone know how I could do that? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#model-examples

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how you want to save the value as post meta, but you don't have a specific post to save it to? Post meta is something that's attached to an individual post.